# How to get the first element of a std::set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I you all,

I found a strange bug in my software.

Inside a while loop where I remove elements from a std::set, I want always to take the first element until the container is empty:

```
std::set< int*> nodes;
// Fill nodes 
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
   nodes.insert(new int);
//
while (!nodes.empty())
{
int* pivot  = (*nodes.begin());
// do some operation with pivot erasing some elements from nodes
}
```

I found that implementing the first element this way works with gcc but not with MSVC, it crashes where I try to dereference the `(*nodes.begin())` iterator.

Do the two implementation of std::set behave differently?

I would like to have a data structure with no differences of implementation, is it possible?

Probably I must change data structure for this kind of operations

Comment: What happens after your dereference?

Comment: What is "do some operation with pivot erasing some elements from nodes"

Comment: just dereference like this *(nodes.begin())

Comment: Are you sure it crashes when dereferencing `nodes.begin()` and not during your element removal operations?

Comment: Please provide a [complete test-case](http://sscce.org) rather than just this snippet.

Comment: @v01d, that should make no difference, the `.` should have [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `*` unless the implementation is broken. (very broken)

Comment: @linello "I want always to take the first element until the container is empty" - surely, then, you want a std::queue instead.

Comment: @Nick
with gcc the programs runs smoothly, also checked with valgrind
with msvc it crashes because can't dereference nodes.begin()

It seems like set::begin() means two different things for the two implementations.

Comment: @linello No it doesn't, the problem is almost certainly in the code you *didn't* post.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you just want to be able to retrieve and remove the smallest element, `std::priority_queue` *may* be a better fit for the task (the big difference is that it allows duplicates, which set doesn't).

Comment: Have you tried a `rebuild-all`?

Comment: Can you give us a concise full example?

Comment: unfortunately not because the 
`// do some operation with pivot erasing some elements from nodes`

is a graph bfs search with removal of visited nodes. this was only a scheme for what I wanted to do.

but basically the bfs function also erases the unvisited nodes from the set and I iterate while the unvisited nodes set is empty always starting from a pivot.
The error I get is map/set iterator not dereferenceable error in MSVC

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear, but "… I iterate while the unvisited nodes set is empty… the error I get is map/set iterator not dereferenceable" makes it sound like you're trying to dereference the result of begin() on an empty set, which is undefined behavior. You might get some previously-valid node that's deallocated but not yet been overwritten with one compiler in one test, and a pointer into unmapped memory with a different compiler in another test, but that doesn't mean the second compiler is broken.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they made me think about the problem definition and I changed the algorithm logic structure, this automatically solved my problem.
The lesson I learned is also that is a good practice always to check existence of elements to be removed before removing them and avoiding invalid addresses issues.

Comment: Just a comment, removing the first element until the set is empty is not a very good design: it is not efficient.  It might be faster to iterate over some container, then clear the whole container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code work well in VS2010, mybe you should update your vcc.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use an iterator on a set like this as removing an element from the set invalidates the iterator.  When the size of the set gets below a certain threshold (based on the initial size when you set up the iterator) it will modify the underlying storage of your data on the heap, which will leave the pointer that is your iterator pointing to crap.

See under iterator validity:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/

(*nodes.begin()) does what you want, you just can't delete from a set your iterating through

Comment: "You can't use an iterator on a set like this as removing an element from the set invalidates the iterator ...  you just can't delete from a set your iterating through" - I think you're not right: you can see from the code snippet OP inits the iterator every time an iteration starts so I don't think it is a problem here.

Comment: "it will modify the underlying storage of your data on the heap, which will leave the pointer that is your iterator pointing to crap" - I don't understand this statement actually. It would be a disaster if standard containers did what you're saying here. The _internal data_ (`int` pointer values) must not change on resizing.